# How to get value from link in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, get

How can I get a value from link in angular 4, I have made *ngIf and I want it to show div based on the value of the link

```
<div *ngIf="get the value from the current href">
```

Comment: by link do you mean windows URL ?

Comment: yes, the current URL

Comment: you have to add 
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="isHomePage()>
```

and in TS,

```
 isHomePage(): boolean {
        return this.router.url == 'yourcheckurl';
  }
```

Comment: There is an error[ts] Property 'router' does not exist on type 'WorkComponent'.

Comment: import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

Comment: and in constructor ( router : Router)

Comment: I did it and the error is gone but the div don't show (return false every time)

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

add router in constructor and method in class

```
constructor(router: Router) { 

}

getUrl() {
    return this.router.url;
}
```

No change html code to

```
<div *ngIf="getUrl()">
```

Comment: If I want to check router url what will i put, eg : return this.router.url=='home/1' or 'http://localhost:4200/home/1'

Comment: That is based up on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

you have to import router in the component

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

if you dont have `@angular/router` you have to run `"npm install @angular/router"`
now inject router in your component like

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }
```

now you can write a method which returns true for your URL

```
  return this.router.url === 'your URL'
```

then you can call that method inside `*ngIf="isYourPage()"`

Comment: what's the url will look like ; last page like this "home\1" or http://localhost:4200/home

Comment: depends in implementation, it should be "home\1" if you define routes like this https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes